# JPA SELECT query identification variable error

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I want to send a query to my PostgreSQL DB using eclipselink with this code:

```
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT U FROM Users U WHERE user_name = '"+user_name.getText()+"'");
```

However I get this error message:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
>   Exception Description: Problem compiling [SELECT you FROM Users you WHERE user_name = 'Swen']. 
>   [28, 37] The identification variable 'user_name' is not defined in the FROM clause.

How do I fix this?

This is (part of) my entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByUserName", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.userName = :userName"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByBalance", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.balance = :balance"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByFirstName", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.firstName = :firstName"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByLastName", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.lastName = :lastName"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByIban", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.iban = :iban"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByCharacterSlots", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.characterSlots = :characterSlots"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByLastPayment", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.lastPayment = :lastPayment"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByMonthsPayed", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.monthsPayed = :monthsPayed"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByPassword", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u WHERE u.password = :password"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findByBanned", query = "SELECT u FROM Users u     WHERE u.banned = :banned")})
public class Users implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "user_name")
private String userName;
@Column(name = "balance")
private Integer balance;
@Column(name = "first_name")
private String firstName;
@Column(name = "last_name")
private String lastName;
@Column(name = "iban")
private String iban;
@Column(name = "character_slots")
private Integer characterSlots;
@Column(name = "last_payment")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private Date lastPayment;
@Column(name = "months_payed")
private Integer monthsPayed;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;
@Column(name = "banned")
private Boolean banned;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "usersCollection")
private Collection<Servers> serversCollection;
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "usersCollection")
private Collection<Characters> charactersCollection;
```

Comment: Care to share your Entity class? because user_name has to be a FIELD in it, and it seemingly isn't. See any JPA tutorial. You could put "U.user_name" as an alternative, but still needs a field of that name

Comment: @NeilStockton i have edited my question

Comment: So you haven't got a FIELD in your class called user_name, so your JPQL is WRONG. Put "userName" in the JPQL ... as any JPQL tutorial would tell you